# Modulo 10^9 +7 python

Tags: python-3.x, modulo

I have a list let's say : [1,3,5,6....,n] to very large number, that I need to report each number in the list in a new list but in "modulo 10^9+7" format in python.

How do I do it please?

I tried to search for it and people answer it's (n%m=p) and the solution is p, but I guess that's not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ways to do it. The first method is called list comprehension, and you can find many examples of it on stack overflow and elsewhere.

```py
list1 = [1, 3, 5, 6, 201, 99121, 191929912, 8129391828989123]
modulus = 10**9 + 7
list2 = [x % modulus for x in list1]  # example of list comprehension
```

or using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```py
list2 = list(map(lambda x: x % modulus, list1))
```

or perhaps the least elegant

```py
list2 = []
for x in list1:
    list2.append(x % modulus)
```